# Ant going to the vertex

Tags: probability, proof-verification, systems-of-equations, combinations

An ant has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of moving to the vertex to its left and to its right in a hexagon. What is the probability for the ant to move from a vertex to the opposite vertex

I found this resolution:

I assume you wanted to find the probability that the ant goes to the other vertex, where the ant can go indefinitely.

Solution
Let the vertex where the ant is on be $P_1$, and let the two vertices adjacent to it be $P_2$, the two vertices adjacent to these be $P_3$, and let the last vertex be $P_4$.

Using States, we obtain the following equations:
$$\begin{cases}P_1=P_2\\
P_2=\frac{P_1+P_3}2\\
P_3=\frac{P_2+P_4}2\\
P_4=1\end{cases}$$By solving these systems of equations, we get:
$$(P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4)=(1,1,1,1)$$Therefore, the probability that the ant would get to the opposite vertex is $\boxed1$.

She is right? Or is the answer $ \frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: If you already set $P_4=1$ in your set of equations ... then of course you'll find $P_4=1$... maybe you meant to say $P_1=1$? Also, what makes you think $\frac{1}{10}$? How do you get to that?

Comment: $P_1$ = probability of reaching point 1

$P_2$ = probability of reaching point 2

$P_3$ = probability of reaching point 3
...
$P_6$ = probability of reaching point 6

$P_3$ = \ frac {P_1} {2} + \ frac {P_4} {2}

$P_4 = \ frac {P_3} {2}

P_6 = \frac{P_4}{2} + \frac{P_5}{2}

P_5 = \frac{P_2}{2}

P_2 = \frac{P_1}{2} + \frac{P_5}{2}

P_1 + P_2 + P_3 + P_4 + P_5 + P_6 = 1$

Solving this system find $\frac {1}{10}$ to get to point 6

Comment: Wait, so now you have $P_1$ through $P_6$?  I thought you just had $P_1$ through $P_4$.  Anyway, either way: we know ant starts at $P_1$ ... so $P_1=1$

Comment: We are simply looking for a sequence of moves, $L$ or $R$, such that we stop when one appears exactly three times more than the other.  Since the ant must move indefinitely until such, you will find that it is certain that the ant will get there, as it is obvious that the probability that the number of $L$s and $R$s are always within a two-count of each other is zero.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! hm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the probability that the ant ever reaches the opposite vertex, that is indeed $1$.  All you need to conclude this is that this is a finite irreducible Markov chain.  That is:

1. There are a finite number of vertices.
2. At each step, the probability of the ant moving to a given vertex depends only on where it is now.
3. It is possible for the ant to get from any vertex to any other vertex.

Comment: Why is it 1? He has already assumed that $ P_4 = 1 $